# Store two columns of a datatable in one string using a separator

Tags: c#

I have a `DataTable` with the following structure

```
ATM Fault
---------    
A01 34256
A02 56346
A03 98946
```

How can I store it in one string variable by using pipe delimiter as

```
string temp="A01|34256,A02|56346,A03|98946";
```

**I was Converting My Linq To DataTable.But i it seems that i can do it in LINQ itself**

```
var diff = dtOpenEvent.AsEnumerable().Except(dtOutputTemp.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);
DataTable di = diff.CopyToDataTable();//This is the Datatable which i want to Convert
```

**How Can i achieve same by modifying only `var diff` statement so that there is no need to convert it in DataTable**

Comment: Complete table in one string or one row?

Comment: How do you get the data from your database?

Comment: Complete Table In One String

Comment: @Grrbrr404 Surely that's irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first concat the `ATM` and `Fault` pairs with a pipe and then [`join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) them with comma:

```
IEnumerable<string> pairs = table
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(r => string.Format("{0}|{1}"
                 , r.Field<string>("ATM")
                 , r.Field<string>("Fault")));
string result = string.Join(",", pairs);
```

Comment: Check Question Edit Can i achieve the same by modifying "var diff" statement ?

Comment: @SagarDumbre: I've read the docs from [`DataRowComparer.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907955(v=vs.100).aspx) again. It seems that it compares by values, hence the `Except` might work. Anyway, it's still not clear what you really want. Otherwise i would have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ and `String.Join`:

```
var projectedList = dataTable
                       .AsEnumerable()
                       .Select(row => row["ATM"] + "|" + Convert.ToString(row["Fault"]));

string temp = String.Join(",", projectedList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
string result = string.Join(",", 
                mydatatable.AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x => x("ATM").ToString() + "|" + x("Fault").ToString()));
```